# Make Overlay move along when Google Map is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am using Google Map V3 API and using overlays to display some images on the map.

**Problem:** When the overlay is on the map, and the map is dragged, the map moves but the overlay remains in the same position in the map container (ie. it does not move). How can I make the overlay move along with the map when the map is dragged?

**JS Code**

```
var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function() {};
overlay.setMap(map);
divLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var left = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(divLatLng).x;
var top = overlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(divLatLng).y;
$('#div').css('position', 'absolute');
$('#div').css('top', top);
$('#div').css('left', left);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use a marker on the map as this is built in functionality?

Comment: I am displaying a div with some content in it, that I don't think can be done with the marker easily. It's a label whose position/orientation and image is controlled by javascript.

Comment: I can change the way I approach the problem by using a marker, thanks for the idea! But will like to see how difficult is it to do without using the built-in marker

Comment: Very difficult, as there is no event raised IIRC when the google map is moved. Certainly nothing that would tell you it's new X/Y pos. You'd need to write some code to listen for mouse dragging, and then move the overlay div along with it.

Comment: If you haven't seen this already, it may show something you haven't written that makes the overlay move with the map. It's long, though https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'll try your suggestion of using the marker. Thanks!